# Prolog remove function

Tags: prolog

Im new to prolog and i want to be able to remove two locations from a list. I use this to check my code:

```
    remove(e,[(d,1),(e,2),(e,3),(a,4),(b,5),(c,7)], M2).
```

But it only removed one out of the two locations (which is e). Can anyone help me? This is the rest of the code.

```
    remove(J, [(J,_)|Tail], Tail).

    remove(J, [Head|Tail1], C2) :-
        remove(J, Tail1, C2).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current version actually gives removes all up to first occurrence of `e`. Try this:

```
remove(_, [], []).

% matches if current head element is equals to remove element.
remove(J, [(J,_)|Tail], Res) :- remove(J, Tail, Res). 

% matches if current head element IS NOT equal to remove element. 
% J \= K checks it.  
remove(J, [(K, V) | Tail], [(K, V) | Res]) :- 
    J \= K, remove(J, Tail, Res).
```

Comment: When i try this i keep getting an error message and dont understand why, the error is:

Comment: Error 42 : Syntax Error

!   | 
!   | 
!   | remove(J, [(J,_)|Tail], C2) :- remove(J, Tail, C2);
!   | 
!   | remove(J, [Head | Tail1], [Head | C2]) :-<HERE> remove(J, Tail1, C2).

Comment: @user1854914 sorry. Evey statement should end with a dot, I used semicolon by mistake. I've already fixed it.

Comment: Just so i can get a better understanding what does the function "\=" do?

Comment: @user1854914 I've updated my answer. Basically it check that head element not equal to or goal element.

Answer (score 2):

if your Prolog has library([lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29)), you can reuse the 'functional' list manipulation builtins: they due their 'functional' behaviour to the fact they take a predicate as argument, being applied (usually) to each list' element (the builtin is [exclude](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=exclude/3)/3)

```
% this must adapt to your data structure
match_key(K, (K, _)).

remove(Key, List, Rest) :-
   exclude(match_key(Key), List, Rest).
```

test:

```
?- remove(e,[(d,1),(e,2),(e,3),(a,4),(b,5),(c,7)], M2).
M2 = [ (d, 1), (a, 4), (b, 5), (c, 7)].
```

I think it's worth studying, because a well crafted library it's an essential part of a good language, and learning the simpler parts will ease your introduction to more advanced ones.